# static check an out of bounds

Tags: c++, assertion

I have this method, that just gets an element of a member, which is a c-style array.

```
constexpr T get(const int&& idx) const {
    static_assert(idx >= sizeof(array) / sizeof(T));
    return array[idx];
}
```

I would like to statically check for a value on the parameter that will try to recover an element on the member that is out of bounds. So, the code will refuse to compile.

I tried with static assert, but, obviously:

```
function parameter 'idx' with unknown value cannot be used in a constant expression
```

What is the idiomatic way on modern C++ of achieve this? Is possible to check it at compile time?

If not, what is the less overhead version of report an illegal access to the member? I would like to mantain the code exception free.

Edit:

```
// call site example

decltype(auto) a = collections::StackArray<int, 5>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto val = a.get(6);
```

I am providing a literal (6), so I was thinking that this value should
be checked at compile time.
Even greater, if I will try to obtain user input for the `.get()` call, code could also refuse to compile.

```
auto in;
cin >> in;
a.get(in)  // Wrong!
```

But also will limit potencial operations like looping over the array
and use the `.get()` method, I suppose. Even tho, the subscript operator could be used instead (without no bounds checking).

Comment: Use `std::array<T>`.

Comment: You want to check something at compile time, which will not be known until runtime. That is obviously impossible.

Comment: `a.get<6>()` is an option, if you only want to allow compile-time values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`idx` is not a compile-time constant, so you cannot assert this at compile-time (which is what `static_assert` is for). You don't know at compile-time what values the function will be called with.

You can use a runtime `assert` from `<cassert>` instead, however that is typically meant for debug builds only (defining the macro `NDEBUG` as typical in release builds will disable all `assert`).

The usual approach in C++ is to throw a `std::out_of_range` exception:

```
#include<stdexcept>

//...

constexpr T get(std::size_t idx) const {
    if(idx >= std::size(array)) {
        throw std::out_of_range("idx out of bounds");
    }
    return array[idx];
}
```

I also replaced the unsafe size construction with `std::size` which gives you the size of an array without any potential usage errors as are common with the `sizeof` construction (e.g. applying it to a pointer instead of a array).

Note that if you replace the built-in array with `std::array`, you get this throwing accessor for free from its `.at` member function.

Furthermore, a `const` rvalue reference is pointless and really confusing (there is no real use case for them). Just take the index by value: `const int&&` -> `int`.

And furthermore the index should typically be of type `std::size_t` to match the natural index type of built-in arrays (and other containers). At the very least it should be unsigned, because otherwise the implicit conversions in the comparison may turn negative values into positive ones and mess up your check. (The compiler should be warning you about this.)

In either the throwing or `assert` case (without `NDEBUG` defined) the compiler will fail to compile the program if the function is called with an out-of-bounds index in a context which requires a constant expression, which is the closest you can get to doing this check at compile-time. But then again, trying to access the array itself out-of-bounds in a context requiring a constant expression will also cause a compilation failure, so an explicit compile-time check is not needed.

Comment: Thanks. Don't want to use the `std::array`, I am coding one by myself (learning purposes). There's no way to mantain the code exception free?

Comment: @AlexVergara `assert` doesn't use exceptions and you can implement it without the `NDEBUG` issue yourself. It basically simply calls `std::abort` to terminate the program if the index is invalid (and in a context required to be a constant expression that forces a compilation failure). But that is usually not what you want in a release build at runtime.

Comment: mmm... `if consteval` sounds great that throw exceptions. Do you want to upgrade your post?

Comment: @AlexVergara Sorry, actually that is pointless. If you are checking the full bounds of the array and you use an out-of-bounds index in a context requiring a constant expression the array access will fail to compile anyway. You don't need any check in that case. You really only need to add a check for the runtime case. Maybe add an example of where you intent the check to apply, because I don't think what I mean with "_context requiring a constant expression_" came across correctly. You cannot cause a compilation failure in a normal runtime call for the obvious reason of it happening at runtime

Comment: I probably explained wrong. I updated the post to try to reflect what I expect for the client code.

Comment: @AlexVergara If you want `get` to be usable only with a compile-time known index, then the index should be passed as a template argument, not a function argument. Then you can use it in a `static_assert` as well. See `std::array`'s implementation of `get`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly was I was looking for. Even tho, is syntactically ugly. I think I will provide it in my API, but also I will provide a `.get()` member method that returns `std::optional` so there's no need to throw exceptions. Do you think that could fit? Even tho, you're answer is pretty good. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexVergara If you consider an invalid index an error (rather than just returning an optional result) and you go the way of reporting errors via the return value consider [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) or a compatible API which will be introduced to C++23 for that purpose. (see also https://wg21.link/P0323R11)

Comment: Ah. The equivalent of the fantastic Rust's `Result<T, E>. But, I guess that there's no compiler vendor that already implements it? Currently, I am mostly using `clang`, and I see no implementation, at least up to the version 15

Comment: @AlexVergara According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp23 GCC 12's libstdc++ has support. Clang is able to use libstdc++ (depends on the setup).

Comment: I am currently working with the `clang's` libc++. But I'll give it a shot. Thanks for everything.